# How do I track the old value in a datagridview cell?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datgridview and I want to do editing of the values of cell on that datagridview. But when I edit a cell value the old value goes away. So is there a way to track or fetch the old value of that edited cell?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also you can play with `CellBeginEdit` and `CellEndEdit` events handlers
And save your current(old) value to the `datagridview.Tag`.

```
void dgv_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    //Save old value to datagridview.Tag
    dgv.Tag = dgv.CurrentCell.Value;
}
```

And then in `CellEndEdit` event handler:

```
void dgv_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //Here you can use your old value from .Tag
    //For example compare is new value same as old
    if(dgv.Tag != dgv.CurrentCell.Value)
    {
        //Do your things with new value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the **CellValidating** event:

```
void dgv_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    var oldValue = dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
    var newValue = e.FormattedValue;
}
```